# vertical alignment of item label in itemize/enumerate lists

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I would like to align item labels vertically to the last line or to the vertical center of the item. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item item1 line1 \\
line2 \\
line3 \\
line4 \\
\item item 2 line1\\
2 line2 \\
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This shows the item labels in the first lines of each items. I would like to place the item labels respectively:

1. in the last lines of each items, that is in line 4 of the first, and line 2 of the second item (aligned vertically to the bottom of the item);
2. between lines 2 and 3 of the first item, and between lines 1 and 2 of the second item
   (aligned vertically to the middle of the item)

Is this doable? (Either without or with enumitem package.)

Comment: Using multirow package and vertically center-align + draw invisible "table"?

Comment: You could load the `linegoal` package and then use either `\item \parbox[m]{\linegoal}{ .. contents ...}` (to make bullet centered) or `\item \parbox[b]{\linegoal}{ .. contents ...}` (to put bullet at bottom). Making this automatic might require defining some custom commands (or redefining old ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well what you want, a simple `\parbox` with the optional argument for the vertical placement (the content of a \parbox is vertically centred by default) is enough:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
    \item \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{item1 line1 \\
    line2 \\
    line3 \\
    line4}
    \item \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{item 2 line1\\
    2 line2}
    \end{itemize}
    \vskip 1cm

    \begin{itemize}
    \item \parbox{\linewidth}{item1 line1 \\
    line2 \\
    line3 \\
    line4}
    \item \parbox{\linewidth}{item 2 line1\\
    2 line2}
    \end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks!